# Connecting to server over WIFI reliably during bootup

Tags: android

There is quite a bit of varience in how long it takes for WiFI connectivity to be established.  I would like some input on what is the best way to get connectivity established.  In particular I am considering how to make multiple attempts to connect to a server where one does not know ahead of time how long it will take for wifi to get established. For example is it better to make three tries spaced apart by 10 seconds. or to make on long continuous try for 30 seconds?  I am trying to make this connectivity as robust as possible. Getting connected to server over wifi in a reliable best effort manner is my goal, and I would welcome any suggestions on how to make this more reliable.  One environment I have is Sprint 3G and Sprint 4G/ Wireless Sierra.  Another is AT&T both 3G and 4G.  Thanks AM I the only one who deals with this? Really?

Comment: How early do you want this?. Once the kernel startup is over and before init executes, it is possible to address the wifi provided that the drivers have been installed. Init executes in run levels 1 through 6. You may control the access to the wifi and wait as appropriate.

Comment: tablet boots.   then two phases  1) get to connect to wifi? should this be a repeat request? every n seconds?  whats a good number for n?  Detect wifi is connected phase 2) start trying to HTTP Connect.  Repeat? 120 seconds wait for several repeated tries whats best. I'm not looking for a way, but the most reliable way to get the WIFI connected, and then establish http connection.

Comment: So WIFI might not auto be connected. Should I try to get WIFI established say 2-3 times. How long to wait before trying to establish WIFI again? 10 seconds 20 seconds?  I want to know some real world numbers on this?

Comment: I'm just wondering here: Is the [`WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED`](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/detect-wifi-onoff-state.html) not accurate enough? (I realize I might be pointing you to your own blog >_<)

Comment: That would probably be the way to confirm. There is probably also an WIF connected broadcast as well which one could catch. Hoer there is also issue of requesting the connection if necessary.  An attempt to connect to wifi can fail. So what I am after is how to space out the wifi connection requestios, and server http connection requests. Lots have done this so I am just hoping people would share their experienc.